# Can I use a generic type in a state variable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to use a generic type in a state variable in Swift?

I have a view which presents 3 buttons. Each button loads an array of items of either `MyGenericObject<TypeA>`, `MyGenericObject<TypeB>` or `MyGenericObject<TypeC>` type and the aim is to then present a list of objects from the chosen array.

But XCode throws an error when I write `@State var objects: [MyGenericObject<T>]?`

The error is there even when working with an individual object instead of an array, as in the following example:

```swift
struct ObjectView: View {

// I would like the following to be @State var object: MyGenericObject<T> instead...
    
@State var object: MyGenericObject<TypeA>? 
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("\(object?.data.name)")

// because I would then like to do something like this, if possible:

    if type(of: object) == MyGenericObject<TypeA> {
        ...show list of item of this type
    } else

    if type(of: object) == MyGenericObject<TypeB> {
        ...show list of item of this type
    }

    else {
        ...show list of item of type MyGenericObject<TypeC>
    }

// or better yet, use a switch

}
```

How can I use a generic type in a @State variable in SwiftUI? And is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Make the whole view generic

Comment: @Cristik If I change it to MyGenericObject<T> I get... "error: cannot find type 'T' in scope"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can get past the error if I use struct ObjectView<T>: View {...} but then for some reason can access object.data but not object.data.name when I feed MyGenericObject<TypeA> into the view

Comment: You need to have a protocol then that your types conforms to and that you restrict your generic type to, ObjectView<T: SomeProtocol>

Comment: I actually have that but still having issues. And that protocol conforms to NSObject, as XCode wanted that added.

Comment: I have, of course, no idea what those issues are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230462/discussion-between-ribena-and-joakim-danielson).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question and took a look at the gist. It's a little hard to tell if this is *exactly* what you want, but it seems like it might get you on the right path:

```
protocol InstrumentType {
    var name : String { get set }
    var int : Int { get set }
    var bool : Bool { get set }
}

class Instrument<T : InstrumentType>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var object: T
    
    init(object: T){
        self.object = object
    }
}

class Trumpet: NSObject, ObservableObject, InstrumentType {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var int: Int
    @Published var bool: Bool
    
    init(name: String = "newTrumpet", int: Int = 1, bool: Bool = true){
        self.name = name
        self.int = int
        self.bool = bool
    }
}

class Guitar: NSObject, ObservableObject, InstrumentType  {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var int: Int
    @Published var bool: Bool
    
    init(name: String = "newGuitar", int: Int = 2, bool: Bool = true){
        self.name = name
        self.int = int
        self.bool = bool
    }
}

class Clarinet: NSObject, ObservableObject, InstrumentType  {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var int: Int
    @Published var bool: Bool
    
    init(name: String = "newClarinet", int: Int = 3, bool: Bool = true){
        self.name = name
        self.int = int
        self.bool = bool
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        _ContentView(instrument: Instrument(object: Trumpet(name: "testTrumpet")))
    }
}

//VIEWS
struct _ContentView<T : InstrumentType>: View {
    @StateObject var instrument: Instrument<T>
    
    var body: some View {
        InstrumentView(instrument: instrument)
            .environmentObject(instrument)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
    }
}

struct InstrumentView<T : InstrumentType>: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var instrument: Instrument<T>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            if type(of: instrument) == Instrument<Trumpet>.self {
                Text("Instrument is a trumpet")
                Text("\(instrument.object.name)")
                Text("\(instrument.object.int)")
                Text("\(instrument.object.bool ? "true" : "false")")
            } else
            
            if type(of: instrument) == Instrument<Guitar>.self {
                Text("Instrument is a guitar")
                Text("\(instrument.object.name)")
                Text("\(instrument.object.int)")
            }
            
            else {
                Text("Instrument is a clarinet")
            }
            
            Button("Update int") {
                instrument.object.int += 1
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

1. Added a protocol `InstrumentType` that defines the available properties on each instrument -- that allowed me to get rid of the `Metadata`, since it was all stored on each instrument anyway
2. Constrained each generic to `InstrumentType`
3. I was a little confused by the `@StateObject` for each type of instrument -- I assumed that maybe what I did was what you were looking for (one generic @StateObject, but perhaps this is where the answer differs from the intent)
4. I was able to use `environmentObject` and `object.name` in the way you were hoping
5. Added a Button to show that the @Published properties propagate correctly.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. In the end I made the code much simpler by changing the individual instrument classes to structs. I have `@Published var object: T` in the `Instrument<T>` class so the instrument variables are all published that way. I had kept metadata separate instead of having at as a protocol, so that it could also use the same trick. I'm not sure if it would work that way with a protocol. Does having a getter and setters in the protocol mean its variables are "published" anyway?

Comment: I think I'll delete this question though, as the gist is too different from the original question, which itself could have been clearer. Thanks for your help though, as I'll try to incorporate a protocol back in.

Comment: No, `{ get set }` does not mean that they are `@Published` -- it just defines that the variable has to be readable and writable in the `struct` or `class` that implements the protocol.